# Android app that needs to login and then scrape some info of the page

Tags: android, authentication, web-scraping

I have an idea for a usefull app for my school.

The idea:

- First screen of the app is a login screen (u can find the login form here https://chamilo.hogent.be/index.php?application=syllabus_plus )
- U log in
- Next screen is some info about your classes.

How can I accomplish this? Are there any tutorials that can send me in the right way? I have basic android experience.

All help and info is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to make a webservice so you can send or retrieve data from your distant database (at your host).

Secondly you need to connect to that webservice on you android app to check sent data.
For example : username and password are correct, if so open the second activity which contains classes information.

here is a simple tutorial : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Comment: So with the first thing you mean setting up a website or something with a database? Or how do you mean?

Comment: You need to create a webservice on your website, check the link i sent. it'll allows you to get data from your database